# Highcharts Stacked Column Chart Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, highcharts

I'm new to HighCharts and I'm trying to achieve a basic stacked column chart like the one in this [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/travishorn/pen/zKmPJg)
My code looks like this

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import { workForceDataFemale } from "./WorkForceDataFemale";
import { workForceDataMale } from './WorkForceDataMale';



const options = {

  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'My chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
   categories: ['2013']
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Total Number of Workers'
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Male',
    data: [ workForceDataMale[2013].map(e => (e.n_workers))]
  }, {
    name: 'Female',
    data: [ workForceDataFemale[2013].map(e => (e.n_workers)) ]
  }   
  ],

};

class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="main-container">
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

[image]

I'm not really sure what's going on with my xAxis but I want to be able to plug in the Year '2013' so that my columns stack

Comment: Hi, you are looping an array and returning every element in there to the chart data: `data: [ workForceDataMale[2013].map(e => (e.n_workers))]`, it seems your `workForceDataMale[2013]` array actually has a lot of data.

In order to achieve the chart that you want to visualize, you need an array with only one value for the Male serie and another array with only one value for the Female serie.

Comment: Hi, yeah I figured that out eventually, also had to remove [ ] from the data for it to render correctly

Comment: Hi @invrt, Has your problem been solved or do you still need help?